# Smooth scrolling is causing extra pages to scroll unexpectedly

Tags: infinite-scroll, gsap, smooth-scrolling, scrolltrigger, locomotive-scroll

I am using Locomotive, ScrollTrigger, and Gsap for animation. Smooth scrolling is causing extra pages to scroll at the end unexpectedly. When I inspect the webpage shows "has-scroll-init+has-scroll-smooth". I tried some AI suggestions but it does not work. Tried fixing the CSS and also the JS

```js
const locoMotive = () => {
  gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

  // Using Locomotive Scroll from Locomotive https://github.com/locomotivemtl/locomotive-scroll

  const locoScroll = new LocomotiveScroll({
    el: document.querySelector("#main"),
    smooth: true,
  });
  // each time Locomotive Scroll updates, tell ScrollTrigger to update too (sync positioning)
  locoScroll.on("scroll", ScrollTrigger.update);

  // tell ScrollTrigger to use these proxy methods for the "#main" element since Locomotive Scroll is hijacking things
  ScrollTrigger.scrollerProxy("#main", {
    scrollTop(value) {
      return arguments.length
        ? locoScroll.scrollTo(value, 0, 0)
        : locoScroll.scroll.instance.scroll.y;
    }, // we don't have to define a scrollLeft because we're only scrolling vertically.
    getBoundingClientRect() {
      return {
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight,
      };
    },
    // LocomotiveScroll handles things completely differently on mobile devices - it doesn't even transform the container at all! So to get the correct behavior and avoid jitters, we should pin things with position: fixed on mobile. We sense it by checking to see if there's a transform applied to the container (the LocomotiveScroll-controlled element).
    pinType: document.querySelector("#main").style.transform
      ? "transform"
      : "fixed",
  });

  // each time the window updates, we should refresh ScrollTrigger and then update LocomotiveScroll.
  ScrollTrigger.addEventListener("refresh", () => locoScroll.update());

  // after everything is set up, refresh() ScrollTrigger and update LocomotiveScroll because padding may have been added for pinning, etc.
  ScrollTrigger.refresh();
};
locoMotive();

const page1Animation = () => {
  gsap.from("img", {
    opacity: 0,
    duration: 1,
    y: -50,
    // ease: "elastic(1, 0.3)",
  });
  gsap.from("h2", { opacity: 0, duration: 1, x: -100 });
  gsap.from("ul", { opacity: 0, duration: 1, x: -90 });
};
page1Animation();

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const joinPage = document.getElementById("join-page");
  joinPage.addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.getElementById("page3").scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  });
});

gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

gsap.from("#page2-aboutus p", {
  opacity: 0,
  duration: 1,
  y: 50,

  scrollTrigger: {
    trigger: "#page2-aboutus p",
    start: "top 100%",
    end: "bottom bottom",
  },
});

gsap.from("#page2-aboutus hr", {
  x: -100,
  duration: 1,
  opacity: 0,
  ease: "power4.out",
  scrollTrigger: {
    trigger: "#page2-aboutus hr",
    start: "top 100%",
    end: "bottom bottom",
  },
});

gsap.from("#work ul li", {
  opacity: 0,
  duration: 1,
  x: -50,

  scrollTrigger: {
    trigger: "#work ul li",
    start: "top 120%",
    end: "bottom bottom",
  },
});

var tl = new TimelineMax({
  paused: true,
});

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const glowButton = document.getElementById("btn-page2");

  gsap.to(glowButton, {
    boxShadow: "0 0 10px 5px #dc143c",
    duration: 0.5,
    repeat: -1,
    yoyo: true,
    ease: "linear",
  });
});

gsap.to("#page3-title h1", {
  x: "-700%",
  duration: 25,
  repeat: -1,
  ease: "linear",
});

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const btnPage2 = document.getElementById("btn-page2");
  btnPage2.addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.getElementById("page3").scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  });
});

document.getElementById("event-page").addEventListener("click", function () {
  document.getElementById("page4").scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
});

document
  .getElementById("board-memebers")
  .addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.getElementById("page6").scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  });

gsap.from("#page3-box", {
  opacity: 0,
  duration: 1,
  x: -50,

  scrollTrigger: {
    trigger: "#page3-box",
    start: "top 150%",
  },
});

gsap.from("#registration", {
  opacity: 0,
  duration: 1,
  y: 50,

  scrollTrigger: {
    trigger: "#page4",
    start: "top 150%",
  },
});

gsap.from("#event-text", {
  opacity: 0,
  duration: 1,
  x: -50,

  scrollTrigger: {
    trigger: "#page4",
    start: "top 170%",
  },
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>CXA</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="media.css" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/remixicon@4.0.0/fonts/remixicon.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main">
      <div id="page1">
        <div id="navbar">
          <img src="/logo/CODE X ARTISANS-logos_white.png" id="logo" />
          <!-- <p>&#169 2024 CXA</p> -->
        </div>

        <video
          id="mainVideo"
          src="/videos/pexels-cottonbro-8721932 (2160p).mp4"
          muted
          autoplay
          loop
        ></video>
        <div class="overlay"></div>

        <div id="tagline">
          <h2>EMBARK ON A JOURNEY INTO CODING<span>...</span></h2>
        </div>
        <div id="nav-list">
          <ul>
            <li id="join-page">JOIN US</li>
            <li id="event-page">EVENTS</li>
            <li><a href="#">PROJECTS</a></li>
            <li id="board-memebers">BOARD MEMBERS</a></li>
            <li>
              <a target="_blank" href="https://srmus.ac.in">
                SRM UNIVERSITY SIKKIM
                <i class="ri-arrow-right-up-line"></i>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="page2">
        <img src="/images/page2-bg.jpg" />
        <div class="overlay-page2"></div>
        <div id="page2-aboutus">
          <h1>
            Welcome to<br />
            CODE X ARTISANS<br />
          </h1>
          <hr />
          <p>
            Where innovation meets passion, and coding transforms into an art
            form. At SRM University Sikkim, our mission is to cultivate a
            vibrant coding culture within our campus, bridging the gap and
            fostering a community of like-minded individuals driven by the love
            for technology.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div id="work">
          <h1>What we do?</h1>

          <ul>
            <li>Full-Stack Development</li>
            <li>Real-Time Projects</li>
            <li>Freelance Projects</li>
            <li>Industry Exposure</li>
            <li>Hackathons</li>
          </ul>

          <button id="btn-page2">
            JOIN US<span><i class="ri-arrow-down-double-line"></i></span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="page3">
        <div id="page3-title">
          <h1>
            SCAN THE QR CODE OR CLICK ON THE LINK TO JOIN THE CLUB. SCAN THE QR
            CODE OR CLICK ON THE LINK TO JOIN THE CLUB.
          </h1>
        </div>

        <div id="page3-box">
          <div id="discord-box">
            <img id="discord-logo" src="/images/dicordLogo.png" />
            <h4>Join our Discord server.</h4>
            <img id="discord-qr" src="/images/discordQR.png" />
            <a target="_blank" href="https://discord.gg/HYY6M2pF"
              >Discord<i class="ri-arrow-right-up-line"></i
            ></a>
          </div>
          <div id="whatsapp-box">
            <img id="whatsapp-logo" src="/images/whatsappLogo.png" />
            <h4>Join our Whatsapp group.</h4>
            <img id="whatsapp-qr" src="/images/whatsapp-qr.png" />
            <a
              target="_blank"
              href="https://chat.whatsapp.com/IpXLyGufoiIK2oIfIrI2vA"
              >Whatsapp<i class="ri-arrow-right-up-line"></i
            ></a>
          </div>
          <div id="phone-join">
            <p>
              <i class="ri-phone-fill"></i> +91 9635654674<br /><span
                >Call us and join the community.</span
              >
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="page4">
        <video
          id="page4-video"
          src="/videos/page4-video.mp4"
          muted
          autoplay
          loop
        ></video>
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div id="event-text">
          <h1>
            <span>EVENTS</span><br />
            are coming soon <i class="ri-send-plane-line"></i>
          </h1>
        </div>
        <div id="registration">
          <div id="registration-text">
            <p>Registration will start for upcoming event.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="page5">
        <img
          id="page5-logo"
          src="/logo/CODE X ARTISANS-logos_transparent.png"
        />
        <h1>Our Vision</h1>
        <div id="ourVison-text">
          <p>
            At CODE X Artisans, in SRM University Sikkim, our vision is to
            instill a vibrant coding culture by offering hackathons, projects,
            and freelance work. We strive to empower students with practical
            coding skills and foster innovation through hands-on experiences.
            Our goal is to cultivate a community where members can collaborate,
            learn, and grow together. By providing opportunities for real-world
            application and professional development, we aim to equip our
            members with the expertise and confidence to excel in the rapidly
            evolving field of technology. At CODE X Artisans, we are committed
            to shaping the future leaders of the coding world.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="page6">
        <video
          id="page6-video"
          src="/videos/page4-video.mp4"
          muted
          autoplay
          loop
        ></video>

        <div class="overlay6"></div>
        <div id="memebers-cards">
          <h1>Meet Board Members</h1>
          <div id="tab-row1">
            <div id="member1">
              <img
                id="member1-img"
                src="/board-members-img/Pushkar Dutta.jpg"
              />
              <h1>Pushkar Dutta</h1>
              <h2>President</h2>
              <h3>BCA - III</h3>
              <h4>puhskarp_dutta@srmus.edu.in</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="member2">
              <img
                id="member2-img"
                src="/board-members-img/gaylsten bhutia.jpeg"
              />
              <h1>Gaylsten Bhutia</h1>
              <h2>Vice-President, Manager</h2>
              <h3>BCA - III</h3>
              <h4>puhskarp_dutta@srmus.edu.in</h4>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="tab-row2">
            <div id="member3">
              <img
                id="member3-img"
                src="/board-members-img/Irfan Ansari.jpeg"
              />
              <h1>Irfan Ansari</h1>
              <h2>Secretary, Event Coordinator</h2>
              <h3>BCA - II</h3>
              <h4>puhskarp_dutta@srmus.edu.in</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="member4">
              <img id="member4-img" src="/board-members-img/Rohit Singh.jpeg" />
              <h1>Rohit Singh</h1>
              <h2>Public Relations Officer</h2>
              <h3>BCA - II</h3>
              <h4>roithm_singh@srmus.edu.in</h4>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="tab-row3">
            <div id="member5">
              <img
                id="member5-img"
                src="/board-members-img/Sonihang Subba.jpeg"
              />
              <h1>Sonihang Subba</h1>
              <h2>Membership Chair</h2>
              <h3>BCA - II</h3>
              <h4>sonihangb.subba@srmus.edu.in</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="member6">
              <img
                id="member6-img"
                src="/board-members-img/Abhimanyu Sir.jpeg"
              />
              <p>Special Mention</p>
              <h1>Abhimanyu Sharma</h1>
              <h2>Mentor & Guide</h2>
              <h3>Assistant Professor</h3>
              <h4>puhskarp_dutta@srmus.edu.in</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="page7"></div>
    </div>
  </body>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/locomotive-scroll@3.5.4/dist/locomotive-scroll.js"></script>
  <script
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.12.1/gsap.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-qF6akR/fsZAB4Co1QDDnUXWnaQseLGXoniuSuSlPQK6+aWhlMZcHzkasCSlnWoe+TJuudlka1/IQ01Dnhgq95g=="
    crossorigin="anonymous"
    referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  ></script>
  <script
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.12.1/ScrollTrigger.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-IHDCHrefnBT3vOCsvdkMvJF/MCPz/nBauQLzJkupa4Gn4tYg5a6VGyzIrjo6QAUy3We5HFOZUlkUpP0dkgE60A=="
    crossorigin="anonymous"
    referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  ></script>

  // Updating the background video here for smaller screen
  <script>
    function updateVideoSource() {
      var videoElement = document.getElementById("mainVideo");

      // Check the screen width using matchMedia
      var isSmallScreen = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 767px)").matches;

      // Log screen width for debugging
      console.log("Screen Width:", window.innerWidth);

      // Update video source based on screen width
      videoElement.src = isSmallScreen
        ? "videos/pexels-cottonbro-8721926 (2160p).mp4"
        : "videos/pexels-cottonbro-8721932 (2160p).mp4";

      // Log updated video source for debugging
      console.log("Updated Video Source:", videoElement.src);

      // Reload the video to apply the changes
      videoElement.load();
    }

    // Update the video source on page load and window resize
    window.addEventListener("load", updateVideoSource);
    window.addEventListener("resize", updateVideoSource);
  </script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

code, though it did not work.

Comment: Can you provide code?

Comment: Yes! Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I was playing with this stuff a little bit...

`Locomotive Scroll` definitely mixes things up here.
If I were you, I would implement a custom scrollbar here.

This solution is not perfect, but it will give you the opportunity to further research.

As far as I know, the implementation of LS plus GSAP is possible, and they mention it themselves, but it may be a bit... *demanding*. Which probably shouldn't surprise you, after all, they have exactly the same product... only paid. If you know what I mean... ;)

```js
const locoMotive = () => {
  gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

  // Using Locomotive Scroll from Locomotive https://github.com/locomotivemtl/locomotive-scroll

  const locoScroll = new LocomotiveScroll({
    el: document.querySelector("#main"),
    smooth: true,
    // getDirection: true,
  });
  locoScroll.on("scroll", ScrollTrigger.update);

  ScrollTrigger.scrollerProxy("#main", {
    scrollTop(value) {
      return arguments.length
        ? locoScroll.scrollTo(value, 0, 0)
        : locoScroll.scroll.instance.scroll.y;
    },
    getBoundingClientRect() {
      return {
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight,
      };
    },
    pinType: document.querySelector("#main").style.transform
      ? "transform"
      : "fixed",
  });

  ScrollTrigger.addEventListener("refresh", () => locoScroll.update());
  ScrollTrigger.refresh();
};
locoMotive();

const page1Animation = () => {
  gsap.from("img", {
    opacity: 0,
    duration: 1,
    y: -50,
  });
  gsap.from("h2", { opacity: 0, duration: 1, x: -100 });
  gsap.from("ul", { opacity: 0, duration: 1, x: -90 });
};
page1Animation();

gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

gsap.from("#page2-aboutus p", {
  opacity: 0,
  duration: 1,
  y: 50,

  scrollTrigger: {
    trigger: "#page2-aboutus p",
    start: "top 100%",
    end: "bottom bottom",
  },
});

gsap.from("#page2-aboutus hr", {
  x: -100,
  duration: 1,
  opacity: 0,
  ease: "power4.out",
  scrollTrigger: {
    trigger: "#page2-aboutus hr",
    start: "top 100%",
    end: "bottom bottom",
  },
});

gsap.from("#work ul li", {
  opacity: 0,
  duration: 1,
  x: -50,

  scrollTrigger: {
    trigger: "#work ul li",
    start: "top 120%",
    end: "bottom bottom",
  },
});

var tl = new TimelineMax({
  paused: true,
});

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const glowButton = document.getElementById("btn-page2");

  gsap.to(glowButton, {
    boxShadow: "0 0 10px 5px #dc143c",
    duration: 0.5,
    repeat: -1,
    yoyo: true,
    ease: "linear",
  });
});

gsap.to("#page3-title h1", {
  x: "7%",
  duration: 3,
  repeat: -1,
  yoyo: true,
  ease: "linear",
});

gsap.from("#page3-box", {
  opacity: 0,
  duration: 1,
  x: -50,

  scrollTrigger: {
    trigger: "#page3-box",
    start: "top 150%",
  },
});

gsap.from("#registration", {
  opacity: 0,
  duration: 1,
  y: 50,
  scrollTrigger: {
    trigger: "#registration",
    start: "top top",
  },
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main">
      <div id="page1">
        <div id="navbar">
          <svg
            id="logo"
            width="400"
            height="200"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          >
            <rect
              width="200"
              height="100"
              x="100"
              y="50"
              rx="20"
              ry="20"
              fill="blue"
            />
          </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div id="tagline">
          <h2>EMBARK ON A JOURNEY INTO CODING<span>...</span></h2>
        </div>
        <div id="nav-list">
          <ul>
            <li id="join-page">JOIN US</li>
            <li id="event-page">EVENTS</li>
            <li><a href="#">PROJECTS</a></li>
            <li id="board-memebers"><a href="#">BOARD MEMBERS</a></li>
            <li>
              <a target="_blank" href="https://srmus.ac.in">
                SRM UNIVERSITY SIKKIM
                <i class="ri-arrow-right-up-line"></i>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="page2">
        <svg width="400" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <rect
            width="200"
            height="100"
            x="100"
            y="50"
            rx="20"
            ry="20"
            fill="red"
          />
        </svg>
        <div class="overlay-page2"></div>
        <div id="page2-aboutus">
          <h1>
            Welcome to<br />
            CODE X ARTISANS<br />
          </h1>
          <hr />
          <p>
            Where innovation meets passion, and coding transforms into an art
            form. At SRM University Sikkim, our mission is to cultivate a
            vibrant coding culture within our campus, bridging the gap and
            fostering a community of like-minded individuals driven by the love
            for technology.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div id="work">
          <h1>What we do?</h1>
          <ul>
            <li>Full-Stack Development</li>
            <li>Real-Time Projects</li>
            <li>Freelance Projects</li>
            <li>Industry Exposure</li>
            <li>Hackathons</li>
          </ul>
          <button id="btn-page2">
            JOIN US<span><i class="ri-arrow-down-double-line"></i></span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="page3">
        <div id="page3-title">
          <h1>
            SCAN THE QR CODE OR CLICK ON THE LINK TO JOIN THE CLUB. SCAN THE QR
            CODE OR CLICK ON THE LINK TO JOIN THE CLUB.
          </h1>
        </div>
        <div id="page3-box">
          <div id="discord-box">
            <svg width="400" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <rect
                width="200"
                height="100"
                x="100"
                y="50"
                rx="20"
                ry="20"
                fill="orange"
              />
            </svg>
            <h4>Join our Discord server.</h4>
            <svg width="400" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <rect
                width="200"
                height="100"
                x="100"
                y="50"
                rx="20"
                ry="20"
                fill="black"
              />
            </svg>
            <a target="_blank" href="https://discord.gg/HYY6M2pF"
              >Discord<i class="ri-arrow-right-up-line"></i
            ></a>
          </div>
          <div id="whatsapp-box">
            <svg width="400" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <rect
                width="200"
                height="100"
                x="100"
                y="50"
                rx="20"
                ry="20"
                fill="brown"
              />
            </svg>
            <h4>Join our Whatsapp group.</h4>
            <svg width="400" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <rect
                width="200"
                height="100"
                x="100"
                y="50"
                rx="20"
                ry="20"
                fill="grey"
              />
            </svg>
            <a
              target="_blank"
              href="https://chat.whatsapp.com/IpXLyGufoiIK2oIfIrI2vA"
              >Whatsapp<i class="ri-arrow-right-up-line"></i
            ></a>
          </div>
          <div id="phone-join">
            <p>
              <i class="ri-phone-fill"></i> +91 9635654674<br /><span
                >Call us and join the community.</span
              >
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div id="event-text">
        <h1>
          <span>EVENTS</span><br />
          are coming soon <i class="ri-send-plane-line"></i>
        </h1>
      </div>
      <div id="registration">
        <div id="registration-text">
          <p>Registration will start for upcoming event.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="page5">
        <svg
          id="page5-logo"
          width="400"
          height="200"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
          <rect
            width="200"
            height="100"
            x="100"
            y="50"
            rx="20"
            ry="20"
            fill="red"
          />
        </svg>

        <h1>Our Vision</h1>
        <div id="ourVison-text">
          <p>
            At CODE X Artisans, in SRM University Sikkim, our vision is to
            instill a vibrant coding culture by offering hackathons, projects,
            and freelance work. We strive to empower students with practical
            coding skills and foster innovation through hands-on experiences.
            Our goal is to cultivate a community where members can collaborate,
            learn, and grow together. By providing opportunities for real-world
            application and professional development, we aim to equip our
            members with the expertise and confidence to excel in the rapidly
            evolving field of technology. At CODE X Artisans, we are committed
            to shaping the future leaders of the coding world.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="overlay6"></div>
      <div id="memebers-cards">
        <h1>Meet Board Members</h1>
        <div id="tab-row1">
          <div id="member1">
            <svg
              id="member1-img"
              width="400"
              height="200"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            >
              <rect
                width="200"
                height="100"
                x="100"
                y="50"
                rx="20"
                ry="20"
                fill="purple"
              />
            </svg>
            <h1>Pushkar Dutta</h1>
            <h2>President</h2>
            <h3>BCA - III</h3>
            <h4>puhskarp_dutta@srmus.edu.in</h4>
          </div>
          <div id="member2">
            <svg
              id="member2-img"
              width="400"
              height="200"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            >
              <rect
                width="200"
                height="100"
                x="100"
                y="50"
                rx="20"
                ry="20"
                fill="blue"
              />
            </svg>
            <h1>Gaylsten Bhutia</h1>
            <h2>Vice-President, Manager</h2>
            <h3>BCA - III</h3>
            <h4>puhskarp_dutta@srmus.edu.in</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tab-row2">
          <div id="member3">
            <svg
              id="member3-img"
              width="400"
              height="200"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            >
              <rect
                width="200"
                height="100"
                x="100"
                y="50"
                rx="20"
                ry="20"
                fill="yellow"
              />
            </svg>
            <h1>Irfan Ansari</h1>
            <h2>Secretary, Event Coordinator</h2>
            <h3>BCA - II</h3>
            <h4>puhskarp_dutta@srmus.edu.in</h4>
          </div>
          <div id="member4">
            <svg
              id="member4-img"
              width="400"
              height="200"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            >
              <rect
                width="200"
                height="100"
                x="100"
                y="50"
                rx="20"
                ry="20"
                fill="pink"
              />
            </svg>
            <h1>Rohit Singh</h1>
            <h2>Public Relations Officer</h2>
            <h3>BCA - II</h3>
            <h4>roithm_singh@srmus.edu.in</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tab-row3">
          <div id="member5">
            <svg
              id="member5-img"
              width="400"
              height="200"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            >
              <rect
                width="200"
                height="100"
                x="100"
                y="50"
                rx="20"
                ry="20"
                fill="green"
              />
            </svg>
            <h1>Sonihang Subba</h1>
            <h2>Membership Chair</h2>
            <h3>BCA - II</h3>
            <h4>sonihangb.subba@srmus.edu.in</h4>
          </div>
          <div id="member6">
            <svg
              id="member6-img"
              width="400"
              height="200"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            >
              <rect
                width="200"
                height="100"
                x="100"
                y="50"
                rx="20"
                ry="20"
                fill="purple"
              />
            </svg>
            <p>Special Mention</p>
            <h1>Abhimanyu Sharma</h1>
            <h2>Mentor & Guide</h2>
            <h3>Assistant Professor</h3>
            <h4>puhskarp_dutta@srmus.edu.in</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="page7"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/locomotive-scroll@3.5.4/dist/locomotive-scroll.js"></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.12.1/gsap.min.js"
      integrity="sha512-qF6akR/fsZAB4Co1QDDnUXWnaQseLGXoniuSuSlPQK6+aWhlMZcHzkasCSlnWoe+TJuudlka1/IQ01Dnhgq95g=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.12.1/ScrollTrigger.min.js"
      integrity="sha512-IHDCHrefnBT3vOCsvdkMvJF/MCPz/nBauQLzJkupa4Gn4tYg5a6VGyzIrjo6QAUy3We5HFOZUlkUpP0dkgE60A=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    ></script>
    <script src="App.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```